# Missing mandatory jurisdiction policy files: unlimited

Tags: java, security

Something to do with eclipse as I can run the code successfully in cmd.
I am using standard oracle Java version 15 and eclipse version 2020-12(4.18.0) on windows 10

```
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

At the line above I am getting error as pasted below.

Please note: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.properties"));` gives null

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.isTransformationAvailable(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at hackerearthpractice/hackerearthpractice.GoalGetter.main(GoalGetter.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Missing mandatory jurisdiction policy files: unlimited
at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
... 24 more

Comment: According to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html, the policy file is not needed for Java 9 and later.  So, my guess is that you are not actually running Java 15 when  you get that exception.

Comment: In Eclipse it shows "JRE System Library [JavaSE - 15]"

Comment: Yes ... but it would appear that you are using a different version of Java to run your application.

Comment: I am trying to search through Run Configurations but can't find anything explicit, do you know?

Comment: Runtime JRE in configuration is also default v15

Comment: @StephenC: to be exact, for 9 (and 8u161)  up the crypto policy files don't need to be _downloaded_ because they are installed as part of the standard JDK (or for 8 JRE), but they are still needed and if removed cause an excepton

Comment: So ... if they are not there, and the OP didn't remove them, presumably that means that the OP is in a country that is barred from downloading the "unlimited" version of Java 15.  Is that correct Tejas?

Comment: (See the "prohibited end-users section" of https://www.oracle.com/corporate/security-practices/corporate/governance/global-trade-compliance.html)

Comment: No Stephen, it was some eclipse runtime causing it. I changed it to the one I have installed and the issue was resolved. I have pasted the snapshot below in my answer.

Comment: Ah.  So I was correct.  Like I said / thought: you weren't using the Java 15 JDK to run the application.  You were using the "weird Eclipse JRE" to run it.

Comment: yes, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

[image: It was using this weird runtime in eclipse, I changed it to the one I have installed and then it worked.]
It was using this weird runtime in eclipse, I changed it to the one I have installed and then it worked.